# Async Json Array Matrix

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, asynchronous, matrix

(apologies if this is a poor explanation)

I am wondering if there is a better why to do this:

```
const arr1= ['cat', 'dog']
const arr2 = ['brown', 'gray']

return await Promise.all(arr1.map(async (one) => {

    return await Promise.all(arr2.map(async (two) => {

        return await AnotherAsyncFunction(one,two)

    }))
})).then(res => console.log(res.flat()))
```

essentially i have nested promise arrays each doing there own map,

which return the response from "AnotherAsyncFunction" in the promise.all arrays,

IE:

```
[{
catbrown,
catgray,
dogbrown,
doggray
}]
```

This is the behavior i want,
but would like to know if there is a graceful solution?

or even if there is already something out there that would achieve the same result

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `return await`s, nor the nested `async` functions - just return the Promises alone.

```
const arr1= ['cat', 'dog']
const arr2 = ['brown', 'gray']

return Promise.all(
    arr1.map(one => Promise.all(
        arr2.map(two => AnotherAsyncFunction(one,two))
    ))
)
.then(res => console.log(res.flat()))
```